# Laurent series expansion for $e^{1/(z-1)} \; (|z|>1).$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Expand the following in a Laurent series valid in the region indicated.

$$e^{1/(z-1)} \; (|z|>1).$$

How can I expand this series? I don't know how to take care of ${1/(z-1)}$ when we need to expand around $0$. The answer says $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z^n}$ where $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{1}{k!}$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: This would be my approach:$$\begin{align}e^{\frac1{z-1}}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\frac{1/z}{(1-1/z)^n}\end{align}$$Then binomial expand...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt How do I work with the binomial expansion of $(1-1/z)^n$ when it is in the denominator?

Comment: You can also use the integral representation of the coefficients, $$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{e^{1/(z-1)}}{z^{n+1}}\,dz,$$ with $R > 1$, and make the substitution $w = 1/(z-1)$ to evaluate the integral. (Well, a different contour will be more convenient for the substitution, but that's cosmetics.)

Comment: @DanielFischer It seems like calculating this integral is quite difficult. Can you give me any tips on evaluating this, or is the first comment's approach easier?

Comment: There's no big difference between the two ways. What integral does $$\int_{\lvert z - 1\rvert = 2} \frac{e^{1/(z-1)}}{z^m}\,dz$$ transform into after the substitution $w = 1/(z-1)$?

Comment: $\int_{|w|=2} \frac{e^w}{(1+\frac{1}{w})^m} \cdot -\frac{1}{w^2} dw$. But this integral still looks to complicated to evaluate.

Comment: $\lvert w\rvert = \frac{1}{2}$, and since the orientation of the circle changes, you get a minus sign. Multiply numerator and denominator with $w^{m-2}$ and you get $$\int_{\lvert w\rvert = 1/2} \frac{w^{m-2}e^w}{(w+1)^m}\,dw.$$ For $m \geqslant 2$, that's an easy $0$. For $m \in \{0,1\}$, it's not very difficult to evaluate, and for $m < 0$, let $k = -m$ and write it as $$\int_{\lvert w\rvert = 1/2} \frac{(w+1)^ke^w}{w^{k+2}}\,dw.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer So to evaluate the last integral we need to use Cauchy formula and put $f(w)=(w+1)^k e^w$. Then I need to know $f^{(k+1)}(0)$, but I'm having trouble figuring this out. Can you give me any help on this?

Comment: You need the coefficient of $w^{k+1}$ in $(w+1)^k e^w$. The binomial formula and the power series of $e^w$ make it not so difficult.